# Post multidimensional arrays with a form

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

I have one list of products and I'm trying to add to cart, with one button, only those products for which it was chosen quantity greater than 0.

I could do it if I put next to each product add to cart button, then can I get id with POST, but how can I add the multiple products with one button?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are working about a web application ? Are you running PHP ? node.js ? Ruby ? .... Are you client-side ? HTML5 / Javascript ? Are you using some client or server framework ? Could you post what your current code looks ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

This is my code

```
$rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM products");
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
 while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
                        $niz = array(
                                array($red["id"],0)
                        );
                      echo "<tbody class=\"js--isotope-target col-sm-12 js--cat-1\">
                            <tr class=\"cart_table_item\">
                              <td rowspan=\"3\" class=\"product-thumbnail\"><img src=\"images/upload/". $red["id"] .".jpg\"></td>
                              <td class=\"product-name\"><a href=\"#\">Appel</a> ( <span style=\"font-size:14;font-weight:bold;color: #71a866;\">€18</span> )</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>". $red["info"] ."</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <div class=\"quantity  js--quantity\">
                              <input type=\"button\" name=\"btnQua\" value=\"-\" class=\"quantity__button  js--minus-one  js--clickable\" style=\"width:18px;height:24px;\">
                              <input type=\"text\" name=\"quantity\" value=\"1\" class=\"quantity__input\" disabled style=\"width:24px;height:24px;\">
                              <input type=\"button\" name=\"btnQua\" value=\"+\" class=\"quantity__button  js--plus-one  js--clickable\" style=\"width:18px;height:24px;\">
                            </div>
                            <a class=\"btn btn-primary--transition\" href=\"#\" style=\"padding:3px 7px;\">
                              <!--<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\"></span>--><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart\"></span>
                            </a>

                            </a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          <button type=\"submit\" name=\"btnSubmit\">Add everything to the cart</button>";
                    }
                echo "</form>";
```

Thus i think that I need two dimensional array, where i can put id of the product and the quantity. The quantity value in the array would have to be updated in relation to the input field(quantity) for each product and than  I would have to pass it with the POST.